# Symfony delete form isSubmitted() return false when CSRF protection deactivated

Tags: php, symfony, csrf, symfony-3.3

Basically this code print true:

```
/**
 * Deletes myentity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="myentity_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, MyEntity $entity) {
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    var_dump($form->isSubmitted());
    die;
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($invitation);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a myentity.
 *
 * @param MyEntity $entity The entity
 * @return Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm(MyEntity $entity) {
    return $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
                    ->setMethod('DELETE')
                    ->getForm();
}
```

But if I change the createDeleteForm() method to disable CSRF protection it print false (isSubmitted() return false):

```
private function createDeleteForm(MyEntity $entity) {
    return $this->createFormBuilder($entity, array('csrf_protection' => false))
                    ->setMethod('DELETE')
                    ->getForm();
}
```

I need to do this because I want to send an email with the delete form embedded inside.

EDIT 1:
Even if the form  is displayed on the website, it still doesn't work so the error is not related to the email.

Comment: a delete form in mail ? why simply put a link to the delete page ?

Comment: Yes I know I think I am going to do that but I really don't understand why it won't work just by disabling the CSRF protection.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

So I finally figured it out...
The form is not submitted because it doesn't contains any field. I debugged the $request->request->all() method to check it's content and I got this with the CRSF:

```
array(2) {
  ["_method"]=>
  string(6) "DELETE"
  ["form"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["_token"]=>
    string(43) "ENi9OFbTVfkJO8IFzahXUGOXe79tamHy3m04vgd7ZbM"
  }
}
```

And without it:

```
array(1) {
  ["_method"]=>
  string(6) "DELETE"
}
```

Then in the file HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php, the following code return nothing (the variable $name equals "form").

```
if ('' === $name) {
    $params = $request->request->all();
    $files = $request->files->all();
} elseif ($request->request->has($name) || $request->files->has($name)) {
    $default = $form->getConfig()->getCompound() ? array() : null;
    $params = $request->request->get($name, $default);
    $files = $request->files->get($name, $default);
} else {
    // Don't submit the form if it is not present in the request
    return;
}
```